# How do I proof that Aut(E/F) is a group? (E is an extension field of F)

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I need help proving this. Should I use the basics that define a group or can I use the fact that it is a set of automorphisms?

Comment: $\operatorname{Aut}(E/F)$ is not an automorphism, but rather a set of automorphisms. To prove it's a group, write down the definition of a group and check each of the properties directly.

Comment: Well, let's get back to basics. A group is a set with an operation on it. In this case, what is the set, and what is the operation?

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes, you can use only the fact that it is a set of automorphisms, *closed under composition and inverse* (and of course contains the unit element, which will be the identity now).

Answer (score 1):

The set of automorphisms of some object, i.e. maps of the object (viewed as a set) to itself that respect certain properties of the object and have an inverse map that also respects these properties, is always a group (under composition of maps as group operation):

- The composiion of maps that respect certain properties of the object aso respects theese properties: If neither of two steops breaks something, the steps together don't break it either. Therefore the compostiotion of automorphisms is an automorphism.
- Composition of maps is always associative, as $((f\circ g)\circ h)(x)=f(g(h(x)))=(f\circ (g\circ h))(x)$ for all $x$
- The identity map $\text{id}$ of the object does nothing, hence repects all properties of the object, and is its own inverse, hence is an automorphism
- Composing the identity with any map yields the given map again, i.e. $\text{id}\circ f=f\circ \text{id}=f$ for all $f$, because $\text{id}(f(x))=f(x)=f(\text{id}(x))$ for all $x$
- By definition of automorphism, there exists an inverse map, which is also an automorphism, and the composition with it produces the identity.